# Data modeling in Prisma with relations

Tags: javascript, data-modeling, prisma

I have a problem understanding relations and data-modeling in Prisma. I have an "easy" example about two users who can participate in a tennis game. So i have:

```
Model User {
  id      Int @id 
  name    String 
}

Model Game { 
  id        Int @id 
  player1   PlayerInGame
  player2   PlayerInGame
}

Model PlayerInGame {
  id      Int @id
  player  User
  game    Game
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error validating model "Game": Ambiguous relation detected. The fields `player1` and `player2` in model `Game` both refer to `PlayerInGame`. Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation(<name>).
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to at a @relation field  as well, but that gave me the following error:

```
model Game {
  id        Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime     @default(now())
  player1   PlayerInGame @relation("player1")
  player2   PlayerInGame  @relation("player2")
}


Error validating model "Game": Automatic related field generation would cause a naming conflict. Please add an explicit opposite relation field.
```

Answer (score 20):

You can fix this error by providing two relation fields on `PlayerInGame`. You have two relation fields on `Game`. Hence you also need two opposite relation fields on `PlayerInGame`. In your application logic you have to ensure that only one of those two relation fields is set. So only `PlayerInGame.gameAsPlayer1` or `PlayerInGame.gameAsPlayer2` should be set according to your business domain.

```
model User {
  id      Int @id 
  name    String 
}

model Game { 
  id        Int @id 
  player1   PlayerInGame @relation("GamePlayer1")
  player2   PlayerInGame @relation("GamePlayer2")
}

model PlayerInGame {
  id            Int   @id
  player        User
  gameAsPlayer1 Game? @relation("GamePlayer1")
  gameAsPlayer2 Game? @relation("GamePlayer2")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do it would be a many-to-many relation. You can add as many users to a game as well in the future and will be scalable in turn.

```
model User {
  id    Int    @id
  name  String
  games Game[]
}

model Game {
  id    Int    @id
  name  String
  users User[]
}
```

You can then conditionally check the number of players in the game and limit them in your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But will this also work when i want to add some statistics, like games won, aces etc. ?
That will be different per game and user, so that is why I thought about adding PlayerInGame.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was having this issue due to a FK being used in multiple fields in the same table. Whenever you have more than 1 relation to a model you need to provide a relation name to [disambiguate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#disambiguating-relations) the relation.

example:

```
model User {
  id    Int    @id
  name  String
  games Game[]
}

model Game {
  game_id    Int    @id
  name       String
  users      User[]
}

model PlayerInGame {
  id              Int   @id
  player          User
  gameAsPlayer1   Game? @relation("GamePlayer1", fields: [gameAsPlayer1Id], references: [game_id])
  gameAsPlayer1Id Int
  gameAsPlayer2   Game? @relation("GamePlayer2", fields: [gameAsPlayer2Id], references: [game_id])
  gameAsPlayer2Id Int
}
```